# spark-cassandra-connector performance: executors seem to be idle

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

On our 40 nodes clusters (33 spark executors/5 nodes cassandra),
with spark-streaming we are inserting about 20 000 per min (among other things) in a cassandra table (with `.saveToCassandra`).
The result we get is :

[image]

If I understand things correctly, executors `S3`, `S14` and `S19` are idle 75% of the time and prevent the stage from finishing... Such a resources waste! And a performance loss.

Here are my conf options for my SparkContext:

```
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "5120")
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "100")
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "100000")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms","60000")
```

Is this behavior normal? If not should I tune the above settings to avoid it?
Does the problem come from the spark-cassandra-connector writes or is it something else?

Comment: this might have to do with how you partition your data? Do you call coalesce() between the stages in spark

Answer (score 0):

On first glance I doubt this is a cassandra connector problem.  We are currently doing .saveToCassandra with 300,000 records per minute and smaller clusters.

If it were .saveToCassandra taking a long time, you'd tend to see long tasks.   What you're seeing is unexplained(?) gaps between tasks.

It's going to take a good bit more information to track this down.   Start on the Jobs tab - do you see any jobs taking a long time?   Drill down, what do you see?